# Document management under Linux

Tags: linux, organization, document-management

after years navigating seas of unorganized documents, I'm starting to look for a cheap/free way to classify our work docs structurally, in order to tidy things up and to better enforce the workflow.. So I'd like to be able to tag documents according to project, customer, components used etc..
For example, imagine these documents:

- "Business requirements", tags: projectX
- "Project layout", tags: projectX, appserverZ
- "Class diagram", tags: projectX, businesslogic
- "Quotation", tags: projectX, customerY

...and so on..
In this way I could filter the documents by their tags, so e.g. get all the docs for a given project, or all the quotations for a given customer, or all the projects using a given application server..
Something like [M-files](http://www.m-files.com) would be perfect, but I'd prefer a Linux-based solution.. :) (even not web-based if it's possible)
I spent all the day trying out DMSes found on Freshmeat and Wikipedia, but I couldn't find one that worked like M-files.. :/
I'd appreciate any hint/pointer, many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene is a great development tool, but if you prefer something that will work out of the box [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/) would work, but it's probably over kill. One of [these](http://java-source.net/open-source/content-managment-systems) will likely work as well.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I just tried a few more DMSes, but no one satisfies our needs :/ Many are overkill, while others miss our point completely.. Maybe we should roll our own..

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might be looking for something like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/), combined with some metadata.

Comment: I'm looking for something that would work out of the box, maybe I should have specified it :) Anyway I perused the "powered by Lucene" list, so your pointer was useful all the same, thanks :)